# UILabel category and setFont: crash

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, categories

I created `UILabel` category which would do extra work when font property is changed.

I have chosen category over sublassing so I do not have to change class for all labels in my all XIB files. I just add this category declaration to the prefix header and category is visible in the whole project scope.

Implementation file:

```
//
//  UILabel+XIBCustomFonts.m


#import "UILabel+XIBCustomFonts.h"

@implementation UILabel (XIBCustomFonts)
BOOL comes_from_nib = NO;


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder_{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder_];

    if (self) {
        comes_from_nib = YES;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setFont:(UIFont *)font_{

    [super setFont:font_];
    NSLog(@"Setting from for label from XIB for name:%@ size: %.1f - do font theme replacement if needed", self.font.fontName, self.font.pointSize);

}
@end
```

The surprising thing is the crash with following log:

```
-[UIButtonLabel setFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ad1b70
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButtonLabel setFont:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ad1b70'
```

**Where did UIButtonLabel came form?**

It happens even if I do extra Class checking in `setFont:` setter:

```
if ([self class] != [UILabel class] || !comes_from_nib) {

        [super setFont:font_];
        return;

    }
```

Is there any way to override setFont: setter in UILabel without subclassing?

Comment: From which class and method are you calling [super setFont:font_];

Comment: As source code shows: it is being called by category itself. The main purpose was to pick up when XIB outlets are being set (font property).

Comment: i mean from which class or viewcontroller have u called this function

Comment: I never call it directly. It is being called by system when loading and decoding XIB into memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call super methods in categories! Never!
This is not possible when you use a category to augment a class' functionality, you are not extending the class, you are actually wholly overriding the existing method, you lose the original method completely. That's why your error appears.

Comment: I never call UIButtonLabel from my code. It looks it is being called by XIB decoder. And about overriding from Apple documentation: "When a category overrides an inherited method, the method in the category can, as usual, invoke the inherited implementation via a message to super. However, if a category overrides a method that exists in the category's class, there is no way to invoke the original implementation.". It looks I do not get the difference between 1st and 2nd sentence in quoted docs properly.

Comment: That's right, Xib decoder is using method setFont: for object UIButtonLabel, which is a part of UIButton.
But the main problem, that you realy cannot call super class, for methods, which were declared in this category. This is the main reason why categories cannot fully overlap inheritance.
Accept?